# HTML And CSS Making a Title Stand Out

Tags: html, css

Hey I am new to HTML AND CSS and I was wondering how one would use HTML AND CSS to create a good stand out header on a website something with a different background to the rest of the page is this possible

So if this is a dumb question

thks

Comment: Your question is probably too "vague" since it is not directly related to CSS and HTML, but to design in general and webdesign more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something Like this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Styling the article element</title>
  <script>document.createElement("mHeader")</script>
  <style>
      Header {
        display:block;
        background-color:#ddd;
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }  
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<Header>My First Hero</Header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file, just define a style for the `h1` tag. (There are also `H2 - H6` if you need them)

```
h1 {font-weight:bold; background-color:Yellow; ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update with your own colors.

```css
    h1 { padding: .5em 1em ; background: #333; color: #fff; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
     
    <h1>Title</h1>
```